# Highlight and Label Line in line chart for Bokeh

Tags: javascript, python, bokeh

I'm dealing with a callback method to create a line chart on the go, given a specific dataframe.

```
def Total_value(DF):
    return pd.DataFrame(pd.DataFrame(DF)['FinalSalePrice'].
                        groupby(level=0, group_keys=False).
                        apply(lambda x: x.sort_values(ascending=False).head(15))).reset_index()

def TOP_Item(data):
    return np.array(data.ItemCode.value_counts()[data.ItemCode.value_counts() > 20].index)

def figure_creator(arr,l):
#     colors = ["#%06x" % random.randint(0,0xFFFFFF) for c in range(len(arr))]
    fig = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=300,x_axis_type='datetime')
    for item in arr:
        fig.line(l[l.ItemCode == item].ServicedOn.unique(),l[l.ItemCode == item][np.int(0)], line_width=2)
#         fig.add_tools(HoverTool(show_arrow=False,
#                       line_policy='nearest',
#                       tooltips=None))
    return fig
```

at the very end I call:

```
show(figure_creator(TOP_Item(Total_value(SER_2016)),Total_value(SER_2016)))
```

[image]

I want to add a Hovertool which could Highlight the given chart and also display the label for the line.

The DataFrame for these is quite big, hence I can't upload it Here.
But the premise of each of the function is explained below:
Total_value: is used to calculate the total value of money, each unique item in the dataframe has made,sort them, and take only the top 15 items.

Top_Item: is used to calculate which of the 15 items has appeared more than 20 times for a 14 day period in a year(there are 25ish, 14 day periods in a year). Further return the list of the items.

fig_creator: creates a line for each of returned item.
**
Is there a way to create a callback method on the hovertool(commented out) per new line that is being generated ?

Answer (score -1):

I figured it out using select tool. Posting for others who might run into a similar problem.

```
def figure_creator(arr,l):
#     colors = ["#%06x" % random.randint(0,0xFFFFFF) for c in range(len(arr))]
    fig = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=300,x_axis_type='datetime',tools="reset,hover")
    for item in arr:
#         dicta
        fig.line(l[l.ItemCode == item].ServicedOn.unique(),l[l.ItemCode == item][np.int(0)], line_width=2,alpha=0.4,
                 hover_line_color='red',hover_line_alpha=0.8)
        fig.select(dict(type=HoverTool)).tooltips = {"item":item}
#         fig.add_tools(HoverTool(show_arrow=False,
#                       line_policy='nearest',
#                       tooltips=None))
    return fig
```

This renders:
[image]